# Why componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) not logging / firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I only have a simple login... now I want to get the value of the newly returned user as you can see in my mapStateToProps function..... but i cannot get it to compare because componentWillReceieveProps() is not even firing :( what am I doing wrong?

i have my component login:

```js
    class LoginForm extends Component {
    
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       email: '',
       password: ''
      };
     }
    
     onEmailChange(e) {
      this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
     }
    
     onPasswordChange(e) {
      this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
     }
    
     onLoginButtonClick() {
      const { email, password } = this.state;
      this.props.loginUser(email, password);
  
     }
    
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log(nextProps)
     }
    
     
     render() {
      return (
       <div className="row center-xs login">
        <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 frame">
    
        <div className="pt-card pt-elevation-1 start-xs formMargin">
         <center>
          <h3>User Login</h3>
         </center>
         <input className="pt-input input"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Email" 
          dir="auto"
          onChange={e => this.onEmailChange(e)} />
         <input className="pt-input input"
          type="password" 
          placeholder="Password" 
          dir="auto"
          onChange={e => this.onPasswordChange(e)} />
         <Blueprint.Button
          className="pt-button pt-intent-primary input pt-large"
          onClick={() => this.onLoginButtonClick()}
          loading={this.props.loading}
          >
          Login
         </Blueprint.Button>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      );
     }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
      user: state.userAuth
     };
    };
    
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(LoginForm)
```

and App connected to redux:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import store from './reducers/';
import LoginForm from './containers/LoginForm'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(store, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

a reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    user: [],
    message: '',
    error: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN':
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            return { ...state, loading: false, user: action.payload, error: false, message: '' }
        case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
            return { ...state, loading: false, error: true, message: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
};
```

and an action creator:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/';

export const loginUser = (email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_USER' })

        axios.post(`${API_URL}v1/login`, { email, password })
            .then( user => {
                console.lof(user)
                dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS', payload: user.data.user })
            })
            .catch( error => {
                dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_USER_ERROR', payload: error })
            })
    };
};
```

Comment: It's not this typo that makes it crash? `console.lof(user)`?

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps will be fired only when you are passing properties from parent

Comment: how how can i get the state returned by the action creator immediately after it fired?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a state in your reducer called `userAuth`.